# Strip time zone part from Time in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone

How to strip time zone part from Time leaving date and time parts intact? Currently I am using strftime function. My end goal is to query MySQL with local time for sure. I should be sure that local time won't be suddenly converted to something else.

Comment: How are you querying MySQL? Which gems are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` as used by activesupport in eg

```
Time.now.to_s(:db)
```

[source](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/activesupport/4.1.6/symbols/Time::DATE_FORMATS?d=137315381&n=0#line=6)

Comment: As for me very nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the same literal time (ie. 10:56 ET and 10:56 PT) regardless of timezone?

Or are you trying to ensure that queries are referencing the same exact time (ie. 10:56 ET and 7:56 PT)?

For the former case (same literal time), just omit the `%z` or `%Z` from the `strftime` argument.

For the latter, I would recommend using Unix timestamps with Ruby's `time.to_i` function and MySQL's `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function